# Unable to access the table contents of ALV List format report

Tags: hp-uft

[enter image description here][[][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dSfd.png)1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtJNZ.jpg)Currently i'm using UFT 12.0 to automate a SAP integrated Webportal. The program generates a report in ALV List format. And i need to access the individual column and its runtime value.
eg: Start Date field and its value "12.12.2017".

Tried using object spy, but it recognises "12.12.2017" as WebElement. Please advice how to capture the runtime values of the webtable columns.

Comment: Better provide screenshot of HTML source code and Object spy window.

Comment: Manish, please find the screenshot attached.